# Errors for socket.io in angular 2 seed

Tags: angular, socket.io, angular2-seed

Unable to integrate socket.io in angular2-seed app.
Actually my code is

```
private mySocket:any;    
getSocketValue() {
    console.log("this.mySocket"+this.mySocket)
    if(this.mySocket) {
      this.mySocket = io(Config.socket_url);
    }
    return this.mySocket;
}
```

When using that code I am getting an error like [image]

Comment: I guess you forgot to ask the question.

Comment: Errors for socket.io in angular 2 seed. 

Actually my code in angular 2 seed app. 

When using that code I am getting an error like.

Comment: Is this question?

Comment: When I am using the above code, i.e. using socket.io in my angular seed app, I am getting those errors.

Comment: Add proper socket.io-parser.js file path in system.config.json..

Comment: I don't have that file system.config.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Socket.io-client not loaded properly
```

Tried below, It worked
npm install @types/socket.io-client --save
define socket.io-client in tools/config/seed.config.ts

```
i.e in SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV->
path: {
...,
'socket.io-client' : `node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io`,// for latest versions of socket.io
'socket.io-client' : `node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io`,// for older versions of socket.io
...
}
```

add in SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG for production mode

```
path: {
    ...,
    'socket.io-client' : `node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io`,// for latest versions of socket.io
    'socket.io-client' : `node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io`,// for older versions of socket.io
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems your socket io is not loaded.!

Include it in your systemJS configuration.

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        ...
        "socket.io-client": {"defaultExtension": "js"}
    },
    map: {
        "socket.io-client": "node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"
    }
});
```

And if u generated typings for it then,

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    ...
    "socket-io-client":"github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/socket.io-client/socket.io-client.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
  }
}
```

Comment: which seed file you are using ?
You have to do something like this
https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Add-external-dependency

Comment: It didn't worked, errors like "**Property 'addPackagesBundles' does not exist on type 'ProjectConfig'**"